# Function not defined in setInterval

Tags: jquery, setinterval

Hallo, I've got something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#all").height($(window).height()-60);

$('a').bind({
  mouseover:function(){
   $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0.8},500);
 },
 mouseout:function(){
   $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1},500);
 },
   click:function(){
 }
});


// CLOUDS SCROLL 

 function cloudScroll(){
     var current=parseFloat($('#clouds').css('left'));
     current += 1;
     $('#clouds').css("left",current);
 }

var init = setInterval('cloudScroll()', 270);

});
```

Seems to be quite easy but anyway it returns: cloudScroll is not defined.
Why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try passing the function directly, using a string is quite obsolete:

```
var init = setInterval(cloudScroll, 270);
```

Answer (score 9):

setInterval is executed in the global namespace, but your cloud scroll function is defined in the anonymous document.ready function.

It should fix your problem and it's also better form to pass function references to setInterval rather than strings (which ultimately get evaled, which is worse for performance):

```
setInterval(function (){ cloudsScroll() }, 270);
```

You could also put the cloudScroll definition in the interval function.

Comment: not sure there is an advantage to using an anonymous function here. Good response though.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
var init = setInterval(cloudScroll, 270);
```

... and if you want to pass arguments:

```
setInterval(scrollCloud, 250, clouds2);
```

**EDIT**
Partrick mentioned that IE doesn't support passing arguments in the above manner. Surprised I didn't now that. Anyway that makes mqsoh's use of an anonymous function relevant. Because you can run a given function with arguments like so:

```
setInterval(function(){
  scrollCloud(clouds2);
}, 250);
```

Comment: damn, I'm, just too slow today. This is the second question I've answered today where somebody beat meat to it :)

Comment: The additional arguments parameter is not supported in IE
.

Comment: +1 @patrick ... damn that sucks, surprised I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the function reference, rather than a string, then it will work:

```
var init = setInterval(cloudScroll, 270);
```

Just to show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/T45Nx/